# What happens when time runs out in Curling Olympics matches?

Tags: rules, trivia, olympics, curling

During the Olympic Games in curling it is easy to see two stopwatches (one per team) with a time that starts from 38 minutes each .

What happens if the time should end for a team?

Has this situation ever occurred?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a team's *thinking time* expires and they have not completed their ends, that team immediately forfeits the match.

Rule C6 (n) is straightforward.

> Each team must complete its part  of a game within the time given, or forfeit the game.

While forfeits have occurred for other reasons, there are no obvious incidents of a "no time" forfeit at an international level on record.